# $\int_{\frac{\pi}{2} }^{\pi} \sec x\ dx$ Converges?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{2} }^{\pi} \sec x\ dx$$

Does it diverges or converges?

Comment: What have you tried? It's possible to find an antiderivative, or you could try to estimate the integrand close to $\pi/2$.

Comment: I've tried $(ln\left | secx+tanx \right |)' = secx$ but I couldnt solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the change $u = x - \frac{\pi}{2}$ (just to make the following inequality look more familiar):

$$
\int_\frac{\pi}{2}^\pi \sec x \, dx = -\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \csc u \, du = -\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{dx}{\sin x}
$$

Now, we know that $\sin x \le x$ on $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$. Can you take it from there?